# Determining if a div contains a table element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

For my accordion, each time the user clicks on the header, i want to see if accordion-content contains a table, if not, generate one and add it to accordion-content. But how do you check if the current element contains a certain type of element?

```
   <div class="a-header"> 
      <ul><li></li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="a-content">
    </div>

    $('.a-header').click(function(){
       var currentHeader = $(this).next();
       //if currentHeader contains 'table'
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there:

```
 $('.a-header').click(function(){
   var currentHeader = $(this).next();
   if (currentHeader.find('table').length > 0) {
       //do stuff
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

both these are good, but a faster selector is

```
$(this).next(':not(:has(table))');
```

Comment: OP is not asking for a selector, OP is asking to check the existence of a table element.

Comment: this selector will in fact only return the element if it has a table, editing to make it !not

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.a-header').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).next().has('table').length) {
    // CREATE THE TABLE
  }
});
```